# How to add content immediately offscreen beneath the bottom of the parallax section which scrolls into view?

Tags: html, css, parallax

There's this really cool parallax effect here:

https://codepen.io/samdbeckham/pen/OPXPNp

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__cover"></div>
</div>
foo bar baz
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
          perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1500px;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: #2D112B;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
          transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
          transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
          transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
          transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
          transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
          transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
          transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}
```

But any text added at the bottom of the HTML is rendered at the top of the page, and doesn't scroll with the parallax.

How can I have content scroll into view, rising from beneath the page, as the user scrolls down?

Comment: great that you've answered your own question. the gap between you asking the question and answering is 11mins. Seems like you haven't tried much before posting here. ;)

Comment: You're right, I didn't try much at all before posting.  I was trying to get free labor off of stackoverflow, considering I only spent an hour fighting with it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to place the content inside `div.parallax__cover`, then change all `margin-left` and `left` to `0`.